# Multiple threads cannot access the same pointer without error

Tags: c++, multithreading, access-violation, glfw

I am making an application with GLFW3 (window library), and I my OS is Windows 8.1.

**My error:** I make a pointer in my main thread and the window's thread gets an [access violation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault) when it tries to use it.

In my application I am trying to make an input handler class that takes in events from the window and sends them to all objects that subscribe to the event.

To do this, I have all objects that want to listen inherit `InputListener`:

```
class InputListener{
public:
    virtual void onKeyDown(int key) = 0;
};
```

To subscribe to an event, a object must use a pseudo-global (reference passed to classes on construction) wrapper variable which contains my `InputHandler`:

```
// My global wrapper
#include "InputHandler.h"
class Centrum{
public:
    InputHandler inputHandler;
public:
    Centrum(){}
};
```

**InputHandler**

```
class InputHandler{
    private:
        unsigned numEvents;
        InputListener* key_down; // Only trying to test on one subscriber for now.
    public:
        InputHandler();
        void registerKeyDown(InputListener* listener, int key);
        void key_event(int key, int action); // Is indirectly called by glfw window (same thread though)
};

// Implementation
InputHandler::InputHandler(){
    numEvents = 0;
}

void InputHandler::registerKeyDown(InputListener* listener, int key){
    // This is called from my main thread
    key_down = listener;
    key_down->onKeyDown(key); // Properly calls function on my Camera class which inherits InputListener
    numEvents++;
    printf("yes %u\n", numEvents);

}

void InputHandler::key_event(int key, int action){
    // This is called by the window's thread (glfw automatically makes this thread)
    printf("failure %u\n", numEvents); // Properly prints out numEvents
    key_down->onKeyDown(key);         // Runtime error here, access violation
}
```

**Example of subscribing to input:**

```
Camera::Camera(Centrum& g_centrum){
    this->g_centrum = g_centrum;
    [...]
    g_centrum.inputHandler.registerKeyDown(this, GLFW_KEY_W);

}
```

Comment: How do you create the "pseudo-global" and the `InputListener`? Is it possible that `key_event` is called before `registerKeyDown` has set `key_down`?

Comment: @molbdnilo `registerKeyDown` is called before `key_event`. I have tried creating `Centrum` as `new` on the heap and passing its pointer through contructions and I am now make it on the stack and pass a reference to it around. `InputListener` is purely abstract and the given example is created on the stack.

Comment: It would help if you showed the actual code that causes the problem.

Comment: @AlanStokes please explain.

Comment: "I make a pointer in my main thread and the window's thread gets and access violation when it tries to use it." Shows us that code.

Comment: @AlanStokes I did. In `InputHandler` under `registerKeyDown` and `key_event`.

Comment: So Inputhandler is shared by all the threads ? yet not heap allocated and no mutexes ? how ? `this->g_centrum = g_centrum;` I think this make a copy, therefore on the thread where you want to call key_event, `key_down == NULL`

Comment: @FélixCantournet I thought that as well, so I changed all the contructions to take and store `g_centrum` as a pointer. The error still persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable being pointed to was dying before it could be used. So, when the thread tried to use it, it threw a runtime error.

Answer (score 0):

In this line you are copying the Centrum:

```
this->g_centrum = g_centrum;
```

You then register with the copy (which makes the first call to `onKeyDown` which naturally works). But you haven't registered with the original Centrum, so it has no `key_down` to call, so when it attempts to do so, without checking if the pointer is valid, it fails.

I'd make `g_centrum` a pointer, and probably use pointers rather than references to Centrum throughout.

Comment: I made everything into pointers and the error still is still the same.

Comment: But you didn't bother updating the question. Or indeed showing how you actually wire this all up. "Questions seeking debugging help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself."

Answer (score 0):

Threads have separate stacks, so objects can only be accessed by several thread if they are heap-allocated.
Furthermore you should protect against concurrent access to those objects (or at least to the concurrent data) via mutexes.

If Camera is instanciated in the windows thread, you will create a copy of centrum.

```
Camera::Camera(Centrum& g_centrum){
    this->g_centrum = g_centrum;
    [...]
    g_centrum.inputHandler.registerKeyDown(this, GLFW_KEY_W);

}
```

You should instanciate your `Centrum`like so `Centrum *mycentrum = new Centrum()` and pass it as a pointer to your Camera.

Comment: Threads can access each other's stack. There is no data race issue in this particular example.

Comment: Thread can access each other's stack I agree, however by default you will be making a copy of the item with the code in camera right now.

Comment: I know this is probably not very simple, but can you manage to provide a working example, so we can reproduce the problem ?